# psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused en proyecto de django

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, postgresql, deployment

tengo una duda con respecto a un sitio, lo estoy subiendo a python anywhere, sólo que al ver los logs, me aparece el siguiente:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
> #011Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Parece que se quiere conectar con localhost pero no entiendo por qué si estoy usando los datos que me arroja la sección de databases de pythonanywhere, sustituyendo address,port, superuser role name y contraseña en el archivo settings.py en la parte de la configuración de mi database:

```
if DEBUG:
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://nombredelsitio.pythonanywhere.com/']
else:
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://nombredelsitio.pythonanywhere.com/']

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
       'NAME':'aquí sustituí por el nombre de la base de datos que cree',
       'USER':'aquí sustituí por superuser role name',
       'PASSWORD':'aquí sustituí por la contraseña de pythonanywhere en la sección de database',
       'HOST':'aquí sustituí por address de pythonanywhere en la sección de database',
       'PORT':'aquí sustituí por el port que pone pythonanywhere en la sección de database',
   }
}
```

Me comentan que eso pasa cuando falta el HOST en la configuración de BASES DE DATOS sin embargo en 'HOST' puse la address que es algo así nombredelsitio.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com, al estar en pythonanwhere no debería poner la dirección de localhost no? por que está en producción.
¿Me podrían guiar por dónde puedo resolver éste problema? Mil gracias

Comment: Si haces un programa en tu maquina local y el código funciona perfectamente, el error debe estar relacionado con la pagina y, si ese es el caso, diría que conseguirías mejores respuestas preguntandoles a ellos.

Comment: No se si es tu caso, pero según el propio [pythonanywere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Postgres/) tenés que pagar para usar postgress allí. También, por motivar a la gente a pagar, podrían tener otras restricciones con respecto a las conexiones.

Comment: sí, de hecho tengo la versión de pago para tener postgres porque la versión gratuita es sólo con mysql

Comment: ¿Si permites ALLOWED_HOST a todos sucede lo mismo? ¿En local postgresql te conecta bien? ¿Para qué es ese debug si las dos opciones devuelven lo mismo? ¿El host lo tienes bien escrito? ¿Debe ser con 'http'? Ya nos contarás. Un saludo.

Comment: hola ya revisé, el problema fue con ésta línea en settings.py: STATICFILES_STORAGE='whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
La borré y el proyecto se ve correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final resolví el problema quitando esta línea en el archivo settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE='whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

La borré y el proyecto se ve correctamente